# How to transfer music from friends iPhone to my laptop

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-transfer, file-sharing

I have been trying to transfer music from my friends iPhone to my laptop but I can't seem to do it. Is there any way to transfer the music from his phone to my iTunes?

Comment: Which OS is running on the laptop?

Answer (score 1):

You could use another app (such as iMazing 2, AnyTrans, TunesGo... you can find a nice comparative [here](https://thesweetbits.com/best-iphone-transfer-manager-software/)) to get files from your friend´s phone into your computer. And then, you just have to add them manually to iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

iPhones can only sync with one computer at a time. If that iPhone is already synced with another laptop, then just use a flash drive to copy the files to your laptop. If not, you can plug it in through the USB, and sync it there. If you can't do that, sign in with his Itunes account on your laptop, and you should be able to download them from iCloud.

Comment: This is misleading in two manners. 1) You don't have to sync to retrieve files from iOS / iPhone 2) you can sync to a handful of iTunes - just that each category of data syncs only with one iTunes. So - this would be correct in the limited case where you wanted to sync music twice without breaking the sync link to the first iTunes instance.